# Using struct constructor to create an struct instance in C++

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, c++20

I am trying to wrap my mind around this talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FXfrojjIo80
I get an error on the following part. It is the simplified version.

```
template<typename... Ts>
struct parms : Ts... {};

template<typename... Ts>
parms(Ts... ) -> parms<Ts...>;

struct first{};
struct second{};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    parms p(first{}, second{});  
}
```

I get a compile error on clang but compiles on gcc. Which C++ feature is this that is not supported in clang? Obviously if i change the `(` to `{` it compiles fine.

Comment: This is [P0960R3](https://wg21.link/P0960r3), which [clang doesn't support](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) aptly calls it "Parenthesized initialization of aggregates".